# Custom scrollview doesn't scroll

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-custom-view

I have a problem. I have my own scrollview, but it doesn't work. The scrollbar appears, but when I try to use it doesn't work. I have tried a lot of things, but none work. The code is:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility") public class myScrollView extends ScrollView {
  private boolean enableScrolling = true;

  public boolean isEnableScrolling() {
    return enableScrolling;
  }
  public void setEnableScrolling(boolean enableScrolling) {
    this.enableScrolling = enableScrolling;
  }

  public myScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }
  public myScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }
  public myScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (isEnableScrolling()) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (isEnableScrolling()) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
       return false;
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
  }
}
```

Inside of this scroll, I have a `relativeLayout` and inside of this a `View`. In the `View` I draw some bitmaps. They number more than it can display the screen.

The XML is:

```
     <com.edjume.myScrollView
       android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_above="@+id/table">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.edjume.myScrollView>
```

And in the activity I use:

```
RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
ll.addView(new Table(this));
```

And finally, in my `View` (Table) has a `OnDraw()` and a `onTouchEvent()`. In the `onTouchEvent` I use the options `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE` and `ACTION_UP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe

```
  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (isEnableScrolling()) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
       return false;
    }
  }
```

should be:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (isEnableScrolling()) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
       return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes. That work. Thank you very much. Now I have to set the goos size becuase now its so big. Thanks again